# How do I use readyState in videoJS?

Tags: html, video.js, mediaelement

I kept running into an issue where I couldn't get [readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState) to return correctly in the HTML5 video player, [videojs.](https://github.com/videojs/)

The standard HTML5 video player simply has you request the state as such:

```
 if (video.readyState > 1) {  
     console.log(videoState); // Returns current video state as an int
 }
```

but when I try to use *readyState* for videojs, it just returns:

```
function vjs.Player.prototype.readyState()
```

How can I use readyState with videojs?

Answer (score 2):

*readyState* is actually a function in videojs, so it needs to be called as such:

```
if (video.readyState() > 1) {
   console.log(videoState());  // Returns 4 (or whatever value the player currently is
}
```